# Филология и лингвистика

Tags: склонение

Даны некоторые русские существительные, склоняющиеся по образцу прилагательных. Они разбиты на две группы:

1: городничий, портной, преисподняя, прихожая, сказуемое

2: кондитерская, мороженое, нищий, сборная, частное

ЗАДАНИЕ. К какой группе относится существительное «вожатый»?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Кажется, отличие между группами все же  есть. Слова второй группы в современном языке  могут быть как существительными (съел мороженое, зашел в кондитерскую), так и прилагательными (кондитерский цех, мороженое мясо). Слова первой группы - только существительные. Поэтому слово "вожатый" я бы отнесла к первой группе.

Answer (score 0):

Существительное "вожатый" тоже относится к существительным, склоняющимся по образцу прилагательных.Т.н. адъективное склонение.

Comment: так к какой группе относится слово "вожатый" к 1 или же ко 2?

Comment: А чем отличаются существительные первой группы от второй? Ничем! К а/с относятся субстантивные прилагательные и причастия (существительные, образованные путём перехода из одной части речи в другую: мороженое, столовая, гостиная, горничная и др.). У них выделяются двухбуквенные окончания прилагательных и причастий, например: выходной, вожатый, рабочий, животное, запятая, учащаяся, позывные.Если разделять на группы, то в одну группу нужно поместить сущ-е, образованные от прилаг-ых, в другую - от прич-ий. В вашей группе все смешано и нет таких разграничений .

Answer (score 0):

Согласна с Ларf (вожатого следует  отнести к первой группе), но можно добавить, что группы различаются способом образования.

Во второй группе прилагательное переходит  существительное (способ субстантивации), а в первой группе существительные мотивируются различными частями речи или являются непроизводными.